# Creating a clickable overlay

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

Afternoon,

I'm having a little trouble with a template and would appreciate a little help of if you can point me in the direction of anyone who can help.

We are working on a new site and have a video portfolio page where it plays a little preview of our video when you hover https://dev.mintyslippers.com/video-preview/

I have 2 goals. The first is to make the actual video clickable as the only way to view the portfolio item is by clicking the link below. I'm guessing I need to add or modify an overlay that would be clickable?

My stretch goal is to make the overlay look more like https://dev.mintyslippers.com/text-sliding/but where is also darkens when you hover like https://dev.mintyslippers.com/shader/

It's all just a user experience thing. It looks nice that it plays a video when you hover but it makes sense to me that it should be clickable.

I've already reached out to the template devs but understandably they dont offer any custom work options.

If it helps I believe it makes use of MediaElement.js and hides the controls.

Many Thanks

Comment: Did you try clickable transparent image above thevideo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach an eventListener to the HTML Element that houses your video. The eventListener you are interested in will be called "onMouseOver()". Check out this slightly modified example I made below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseover_event

```
let videoElement = document.getElementById("yourVideoElement");
videoElement.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { 
  // highlight the mouseover target
  event.target.style.color = "purple";

  // reset the color after a short delay
  setTimeout(function() {
    event.target.style.color = "";
  }, 500);
}, false);
```